# AS3 Sprite added to Stage but not visible

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, air

I'm trying to get a simple AS3 app up and running, and for some reason, I cannot get a sprite to show.  At this point, all I want to do is get a red sprite to fill the stage.

```
public class Main extends Sprite 
{       
    public function Main():void 
    {
        super();

        stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
        stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;

        var square:Sprite = new Sprite();   

        square.width = stage.stageWidth;
        square.height = stage.stageHeight;
        square.x = square.width / 2;
        square.y = square.height / 2;

        square.graphics.clear();
        square.graphics.lineStyle(3, 0xFF0000);
        square.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000);
        square.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, width, height);
        square.graphics.endFill();

        square.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, addedToStage);
        square.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);

        addChild(square);
     }

     private function addedToStage(e:Event):void 
     {
          trace("Added sprite to stage");           
     }
     private function onClick(e:Event):void 
     {
          trace("Got click on sprite");         
     }      
}
```

The trace shows that the sprite was added to the stage, but nothing is displayed, and if I click on it, the onClick function never gets called.  If I use a TextField instead of a Sprite, it displays just fine.  There must be something weird about Sprites.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to set the width and height for a empty `Sprite` will return 0. Have a look at [here](http://www.kirupa.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-274593.html).

and

Refer Mr.Marty Wallace's answer.

Comment: I actually just got what you meant, sorry. `+1`

Comment: Your linked item explained it best.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is here:

```
square.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, width, height);
```

The values for `width` and `height` in this line are `0`. The reason being that they are referring to the `width` and `height` properties of the class you're working within (`Main` - properties inherited from [`DisplayObject`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html)) which will be zero based on what I can see.

You're essentially saying:

```
square.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Which will render nothing.

Comment: OK, but when I changed the drawRect() so it uses stage.stageWidth and stage.stageHeight, I still don't see anything.  Also - see a few lines above where I set the width and height - wouldn't that set the width and height correctly?